# Is it possible to auto-format your code in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, formatting, dreamweaver, code-formatting

Is it possible to auto-format your code in Dreamweaver like in Visual Studio (ctrl+k+d)

Answer (score 99):

A quick Google search turns up these two possibilities:

- Commands > Apply Formatting
- Commands > Clean up HTML

Answer (score 51):

Commands > Apply Source Formatting.

Works a treat.

Answer (score 29):

For the **2017 CC release** this has been moved (after many years of habit development). Find it now at:

> Edit > Code > Apply Source Formatting.

It may be prudent to set up a keyboard shortcut if this is something you'll need regularly.

> Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts

Answer (score 6):

Following works perfectly for me:
 -*click on **COMMAND** and click on **APPLY SOURCE FORMATTING**
 - *And click on **Clean Up HTML**

Thank you PEKA

Answer (score 2):

This is the only thing I've found for JavaScript formatting in Dreamweaver. Not many options, but it seems to work well.

JavaScript source format extension for dreamweaver: **[Adobe CFusion](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=2107536)**

Answer (score 2):

I tried some of the sources online and finally, the below selection works fine for me (Dreamweaver on Mac). For versions above **Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2017 and above**:

Adobe says:

> Edit > Code > Apply Source Formatting

Moreover, full documentation with other supporting information for tasks such as setting defaults, etc. on https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/format-code.html.

Answer (score 1):

And for JavaScript source format you can use Dreamweaver JavaScript source formatting extension.(available on adobe)

Comment: Please also provide link to the resource you are forwarding at

Answer (score 1):

Auto formatting can be done by

- Select View > Code View Options
- Click the View Options button [image]  in the toolbar at the top of Code view or the Code inspector.

**Auto Indent** Makes your code indent automatically when you press Enter while writing code.

[**source**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7be0a.html#)

Answer (score 1):

Please use shortcut key alt+c+a

Answer (score 0):

Please click on "edit" -> then keyboard shortcuts. It`s straight forward from there. Just select the command from the list, and press the + button.

You will need to create a duplicate set, then select it again from the list. And finally set a keyboard shortcut!

Now, before saving, press the shortcut you just created!

Answer (score 0):

Coding toolbar (Edit > Toolbars > Coding) and select Code Format Settings to set your preferred formatting.

You can also access the formatting option from Commands > Apply Source Formatting or only apply it to a select block of code by selecting the Apply Source Formatting to Selection option.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/10-useful-dreamweaver-tips-for-beginners/

Answer (score -1):

ctrl+a->(click)commands->cleanup word HTML