# How to make code neater in Dreamweaver?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

is there any quick and easy way to convert code from looking like this:

```
<style>
element { property:value; property:value; 
property:value; 
property:value; }

element { property:value; property:value; property:value; property:value; property:value; }
element {property:value; property:value; property:value; 
property:value; 
property:value; property:value; 
}
</style>
<div>
content content content <div> content </div>
  </div>
```

to being nice and neat like this:

```
<style>

element { property:value; property:value; property:value; property:value; }

element { property:value; property:value; property:value; property:value; }

element { property:value; property:value; property:value; property:value; }

</style>

<div>
content content content 
      <div> 
          content 
      </div>
</div>
```

it would also make life easier if there was a button to put css in alphabetical order

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to auto-format your code in Dreamweaver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146862/is-it-possible-to-auto-format-your-code-in-dreamweaver)

Answer (score 1):

See these similar questions / answers:

- [Is it possible to auto-format your code in Dreamweaver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146862/is-it-possible-to-auto-format-your-code-in-dreamweaver)
- [dreamweaver CS5 code formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847689/dreamweaver-cs5-code-formatter)

I do not have Dreamweaver installed myself, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146902/700926) the following commands should be available:

- Commands > Apply Formatting
- Commands > Clean up HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Command -> Apply Source Formatting
```